# Kernel dies with strange behavior

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, spyder

I have a simple function exhibiting strange behavior. I already searched for explanations, but couldn't find any.

```
def myfunc(frame):
  lol = []
  for i in range(frame.shape[0]):
    if frame.iloc[i,3] == 3:
      lol.append(frame.iloc[i,7])
  return np.asarray(lol,dtype=np.int32)

print('before')

x = myfunc(x)

print('after')
```

The result of the above code is

> before
> Kernel died

```
def myfunc(frame):
  lol = []
  for i in range(frame.shape[0]):
    if frame.iloc[i,3] == 3:
      lol.append(frame.iloc[i,7])
  print('myfunc')
  return np.asarray(lol,dtype=np.int32)

print('before')

x = myfunc(x)

print('after')
```

how ever, simply adding a single print statement gives

> before
> myfunc
> after
> Kernel died

The print statement is the only difference and I've tested this, maybe,  50 times. Disregarding my other problems (Kernel died), I have no idea why this is happening. I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: what is x? ....

Comment: Sorry, thought it was clear. x is a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error with the sample data, and it worked fine for me.
You can try the same with your data in colab environment and check, if the error doesn't appear then the issue might be one of the following.

1. Your data is large and it does not fit into memory, you can try specifying `engine='python'` while loading csv file `df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', engine='python')`.
   You can alternatively split the dataframe into multiple dataframes and merge it later.
2. You can use Tensorflow's [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) to load CSV files and to build input pipelines which is more efficient for large files.

Below is the working code with sample data.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("/content/sample_data/mnist_train_small.csv") 
def myfunc(frame):
  lol = []
  for i in range(frame.shape[0]):
    if frame.iloc[i,3] == 3:
      lol.append(frame.iloc[i,7])
  return np.asarray(lol,dtype=np.int32)

print('before')

x = myfunc(df)

print('after')
```

Result:

```
before
after
```

Comment: Your answer did not directly address the problem. I wasn't asking about the possible reasons for the kernel dying. I was asking about the strange behavior. I already know that it was not a problem with trying to load to large of a file because I could load it before with no problem. Additionally, I completely uninstalled, then reinstalled Anaconda, and the dying kernel problem went away. Might you have any insight into the strange behavior (which was purpose of my post)?

Comment: If reinstalling Anaconda worked for you then this might be the reason of the older version of Tensorflow and other dependent libarries.